# Debugging code through KGDB

Tags: remote-debugging

I want to debug my code which has some kernel module also. I am able to set breakpoints in kernel as well as in my code. Performing operation hits breakpoints set in kernel code but doesn't hit the breakpoints in my code.

target machine : Machine on which code is to be debugged
host machine : Machine which is used to debug the code

Steps followed:
on host :

```
$ gdb vmlinux
(vmlinux copied  from target machine )                                                                                                                                                         
$ gdb> target remote /dev/ttyS1   
$ cont
 continuing
```

on target :
    $ insmod mymodule.ko
    $ cd /sys/module/mymodule/sections/
    $ cat .data
    $ cat .rodata
    $ cat .bss
    $ cat .text

```
$ echo "g" > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

on host :

```
    $ add-symbol-file <module_name> <address> \
 -s .bss    <address> \
 -s .rodata <address> \
 -s .data   <address>   
$ b file_name //set break points    
$ c
 continuing
```

on target: 
         execute the command(program) .....but it does not hit the breakpoints......finishes the execution without hitting breakpoints.

But when I tried to set breakpoints to some kernel function like vfs_read(), break-point is being hit.

Comment: Is debugging working for other than kernel modules and have you set the tty parameters i.e. `echo ttyXXX,baudrate > /sys/module/kgdboc/parameters/kgdboc` ?